# How to determine the project type in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How can one determine the "type" of a project in Visual Studio?

For example, if a project is a class library, a web application project, a WinForms project, a WCF project, etc. The icons are obviously different for a lot of them, but is there anywhere where it states the project type?

Comment: Have you looked in the project file?

Comment: Any FULL list of known project type Guids, included Sharepoint projects?

Comment: This link includes all the GUIDs in my projects as well as several Sharepoint project types: https://www.codeproject.com/reference/720512/list-of-visual-studio-project-type-guids

Answer (score 34):

One simple trick is drag and drop project file in notepad and where you can see this kind of stuff<

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>`enter code here`
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{27F8327B-239F-4125-809C-13FB6209D2E3}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`enter code here`
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WpfApplication1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WpfApplication1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Compare "ProjectTypeGuid" with this [Link](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx). by changing this guid you can add WPF window to WinForms project.

Comment: Is this still relevant?  The `.csproj` file for a project I created in VS2015 has no `<ProjectTypeGuids>` field whatsoever.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Alternative link for ProjectTypeGuid mappings: https://www.codeproject.com/reference/720512/list-of-visual-studio-project-type-guids

Comment: OUT OF DATE.  Waste no time pursuing these paths to nowhere.

Answer (score 4):

### If the *`.csproj`* file has no `<ProjectTypeGuids>`

As Alex McMillan has pointed out, you could not be able to find the **`<ProjectTypeGuids>`** element.

The first answer is correct, **except for `.dll` Library Projects**, **Console Applications** and **WinForms Applications** as far I know.

They contain **`<OutputType>`** (followed by: ***Library*** or ***Exe*** or ***WinExe***)

and do **not** contain  **`<ProjectTypeGuids>`**.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you go to the properties window of your project you will see the information following this image below.

[image]

Please look at the output type. It shows Class library. If your project shows windows application then the output is a Windows Application.

Comment: Unfortunately different types of project show up as Class Library.  eg if you create two projects, a Class Library project and a Web Application project, they will both have an output type of Class Library.

Comment: It is output type not the project type.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, using the `EnvDTE` namespace, you can investigate the `Project.Kind` property of the Visual Studio project.

However, if you're interested in a more detailed, the project specification file, i.e. the `*.csproj`, `*.vbproj`, among others describes the kind of the project in an XML way.

Comment: In which element within  *.csproj , there is some info about project type? I could not find it in visual studio 2010

Comment: I found my .vbproj file in the main project folder. So this, for me, is the same folder that my bin folder is i, Views is there too, and the .sln file.

Comment: ```Project.Kind``` is about project guid.

Answer (score -2):

Easy solution.

If you want to know if it's a WCF Project or ASP.NET Web Service simply open your project's folders in File Explorer. You can hover over the icon with your mouse and a tooltip will display the project type as shown in the picture. Also, you can look under the **Type** column in File Explorer and it shows it there as well.

WCF Web Service Project:
[image: WCF Web Service]

ASP.NET Web Service Project:
[image: ASP.NET Web Service]

Also to note, if your project has a Resources.Designer.cs or Settings.Designer.cs in its **Properties** folder it's likely a WinForms application.

Comment: This just describes the extension. Nothing to do with project type.