# How to determine the .NET project/template type in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Could you please tell me how to determine the type of an existing .NET project in Visual Studio? By the project type I mean: C# application, WPF application, etc.

I have been transfered a bunch of projects from my coworker. There are many Library projects, each of them does a separate job such as: Declare entities, do sync.

All of them have the same icon on Visual Studio Solution Explorer. I just want to know which template these projects based on.

Comment: That's not a *project type*, that's a *template* that the project was based upon. So, I doubt determining which template a given project came from is always possible, because a project may just have been altered sufficiently to not match any of the templates in the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [determine project type in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031952/determine-project-type-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess by project type you think of the project template used to create the project...

to find the output type right click on Project -> Properties -> Application -> Output Type

As for the difference between c# and other projects: c# project files have the file extension .csproj while i.e. VB projects use .vbproj

Answer (score 17):

One of the XML Tags inside the project's `.csproj/.vbproj` file is the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element.
This tag holds the type of the project.

Here is a **[translation from the GUID to the type of the project](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx)**

So a WPF project, written in C# will have 2 GUIDs, one for WPF and one for C#:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Yet a WPF project in VB.Net will look like this:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Notice the first GUID is the same since it's a WPF application, the second GUID changed to reflect C# vs VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution.

If you want to know if it's a WCF Project or ASP.NET Web Service simply open your project's folders in File Explorer. You can hover over the icon with your mouse and a tooltip will display the project type as shown in the picture. Also, you can look under the **Type** column in File Explorer and it shows it there as well.

WCF Web Service Project:
[image: WCF Web Service]

ASP.NET Web Service Project:
[image: ASP.NET Web Service]

Also to note, if your project has a Resources.Designer.cs or Settings.Designer.cs in its **Properties** folder it's likely a WinForms application.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a project is an application vs a library find the Output Type. In Visual Studio:

1. Right click on the project
2. Click Properties > Application > Look under "Output type:"
3. It will be a "Console Application", "Windows Application", or "Class Library"