# On an existing service fabric application project, where can I find the type of the project template that was used to create the project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric, visual-studio-project

I am analyzing an existing service fabric project. Where can I find the type of the project template that was used to create the project?

Project Type:

[image]

Project Template:

[image]

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600343/12808204 seems to answer your question.

Comment: There is no ProjectTypeGuids tag in my project's .sfproj file