# What are the different project output types used for?

Tags: c#, rider

There are different output types for C# projects.
Of course the output type "Console application" is used for console apps but what is for example the difference between a "Class library" and a "library".

Could someone give me an explanation to each output type and what they are used for?

[image]

### Edit

"library" and "module" only exist in Rider.
Could someone also add why rider has these 2 types and what they are used for to there answer?

[image]

Comment: I assume there is no "short" answer to this. In particular we have no clue how detailed "short" should be, as we have no clue on your context and your environment.

Comment: well in that case i would also take a long answer.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I am thinking of a broad answer i mean the output types are the same no matter if you create an ASP or WPF or what ever application. If they have different porpoises in different situations that could be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Only the first 3 entries are normal.  The bad casing for "library" is notable, hard to guess how this happened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600149/how-to-determine-the-net-project-type-in-visual-studio

Comment: @HansPassant Ok i just found out that "library" and "module" are only displayed in Rider but not in Visual Studio

Comment: You might have some luck dropping to a cmd line and running `dotnet new list`. Then, for any that you want more info about, do `dotnet new [template name] -h`

Comment: I'm a Rider user as well, but I don't have _library_ in the list of output types with `2022.3`. Do you have any additional templates installed?

Comment: Do you also use c# 7.0?