# Change output type in Visual Studio 2012-2015.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, visual-studio-2015, asmx

I used to using Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. I need to change the output type of a  Web Service project to a Class Library. In order to get the .dll of the asmx.

When I use VS2008, I do:

1. Right Click the project in the Solution Explorer
2. Click Properties
3. Select Application in the Properties Window
4. Click on the Output Type Combobox and change that to Class Library.

However, the above procedure does not work anymore in VS 2012 or VS 2015. Is there any other way to generate a DLL from an ASMX file? Thank you!

Comment: refer this link it might help to you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031952/determine-project-type-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same problem.
I tested this on Visual Studio 2015.
1. Right click on your project and select properties
2. Under "configuration properties" select general > project defaults > configuration type.

[as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZi9l.png)